# How to implement inherit variables from a subclass to populate an array from user input?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I have this assignment for my Java class:

1. Make your Shapes comparable add: "implements Comparable" and create the method: public int compareTo(Object o){ ... }
   to the abstract class Shape (so all the Shapes inherit it). For the comparison use the Shapes' area.
2. Create a driver (called Driver.java) that:
   a) creates an array of shapes (ask user for the size)

b) in a loop, populate the array. (ask user what shape to create and the parameters need to create each shape)

c) print out the unsorted array

d) sort the array (I will post an implementation of SelectionSort in a file called SelectioSort.java)
e) print out sorted array

Extra credit
Use the authors ReadInt and ReadDouble to get all users input (in a file called ReadData.java)

My problem is populating the array to create each shape in class Driver. I can't figure out how to inherit the variables from each subclass using switch.

```
// Driver.java
// Driver for testing the sorting of simple Shapes (hierarchy: point, square, cube, circle, & cylinder)
//   it creates an array of shapes 
//   it populate the array
//   print out the unsorted array (area & volume of each shape)
//   sort the array using an implementation of SelectionSort (shapes need to implement Comparable)
//   and lastly print out sorted array (area & volume of each shape)
// Needs: Shape.java, Point.java, Square.java, Cube.java, Circle.java, Cylinder.java & SelectioSort.java

import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Shape[] arrayOfShapes; //holds the list
        int choice; //code number for each type of figure

        System.out.println("How many data you want to input? ");
        int size = ReadData.readInt();
        System.out.println("Enter: " + size);
        System.out.println("\n");
        arrayOfShapes = new Shape[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfShapes.length; i++) {
            Point point;
            Square square;
            Cube cube;
            Circle circle;
            Cylinder cylinder;

            System.out.println("What Shape do you want to create?");
            System.out.println("1. Point");
            System.out.println("2. Square");
            System.out.println("3. Cube");
            System.out.println("4. Circle");
            System.out.println("5. Cylinder");
            System.out.println("Choose one:");
            choice = ReadData.readInt();
            System.out.println("\n");
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    arrayOfShapes[i] = new Point(x, y);
                    System.out.println("Please enter Coordinate 1: ");
                    System.out.println("Please enter Coordinate 2: ");
                    s = ReadData.readDouble();
                    System.out.println(x);
                    y = ReadData.readDouble();
                    System.out.println(y);
                    System.out.println(point);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    arrayOfShapes[i] = new Square(side, x, y);
                    System.out.println("Please enter the 3 size of square: ");
                    side = ReadData.readDouble();
                    x = ReadData.readDouble();
                    y = ReadData.readDouble();
                    System.out.println(square);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    arrayOfShapes[i] = new Cube(depth, x, y);
                    System.out.println("Please enter the 3 size of Cube: ");
                    depth = ReadData.readDouble();
                    x = ReadData.readDouble();
                    y = ReadData.readDouble();
                    System.out.println(cube);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    arrayOfShapes[i] = new Circle(radius, x, y);
                    radius = ReadData.readDouble();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the radius for circle: ");
                    radius = ReadData.readDouble();
                    System.out.println(circle);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    arrayOfShapes[i] = new Cylinder(height, x, y, radius);
                    System.out.println("Please enter the height of Cylinder: ");
                    height = ReadData.readDouble();
                    System.out.println(cylinder);
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        DecimalFormat precision2 = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        // Loop through arrayOfShapes and print the name, area, and volume of each object.
        System.out.println(" Before we sort on area we have :");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfShapes.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrayOfShapes[i].getName() + ": " + arrayOfShapes[i].toString());
            System.out.print(" volume = " + precision2.format(arrayOfShapes[i].volume()));
            System.out.println(" AREA = " + precision2.format(arrayOfShapes[i].area()));
        }

        SelectionSort.sort(arrayOfShapes, arrayOfShapes.length);

        System.out.println(" After we sort the array we have :");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfShapes.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrayOfShapes[ i].getName() + ": " + arrayOfShapes[ i].toString());
            System.out.print(" volume = " + precision2.format(arrayOfShapes[ i].volume()));
            System.out.println(" AREA = " + precision2.format(arrayOfShapes[ i].area()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfShapes.length; i++) {
        Point point;
        Square square;
        Cube cube;
        Circle circle;
        Cylinder cylinder;

        System.out.println("What Shape do you want to create?");
        System.out.println("1. Point");
        System.out.println("2. Square");
        System.out.println("3. Cube");
        System.out.println("4. Circle");
        System.out.println("5. Cylinder");
        System.out.println("Choose one:");
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n");
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:

                System.out.println("Please enter Coordinate 1: ");
                int x = scanner.nextDuoble();
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println("Please enter Coordinate 2: ");
                int y = scanner.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(y);
                point = new Point(x,y);
                arrayOfShapes[i] = point;
                System.out.println("(" + point.getX() + "," + point.getY() + ")");
                break;

        ...
        ...
```

You should have matching `getData()` methods for all your data fields in your classes so that you can print them out like `System.out.println("(" + point.getX() + "," + point.getY() + ")");` If you just do `System.out.println(point)`, you will get a weird print out, unless you override the `toString()` method from the `Object` class, which every class inherits.  For example:

```
// this should be somewhere in each of your classes (if you choose to)
@Override
public String toString() {
    // Whatever you want the print out to be for this class
}
```

**Edit with class**

```
// Classes should look something like this
public class Point {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

**Edit: with example `conpareTo()` method**

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Shape o) {
    if (this.getArea() > o.getArea())
        return 1;
    else if (this.getArea() == o.getArea())
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: that fix the errors, the only thing is not doing is calculating the area and volume.

Comment: Make sure all your `arrayOfShapes[i] = new Cube(depth, x, y);`s go after all you input variable, like in my example. If you leave them in the beginning of the `case` block, the Object will be created before you get values for them.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake on my comment.  After i added        System.out.println("(" + point.getX() + "," + point.getY() + ")");  i get an error where point hasn't been initilized.

Comment: This is my Point class, which is look similar to yours.

Comment: nevermind, won't let me post my code for Point class, but it looks the same to yours.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? is it an runtime error or compile error?

Comment: See the edit. I made a minor change to the `case` block.  `point = new Point(x,y);
                arrayOfShapes[i] = point;`. You should do this with all of your `case` blocks.

Comment: yes i did, just having trouble with Cylinder. Where it says no suitable constructor found in Cylinder (double, double, double)

Comment: First of all, do you know what a constructor is? If not, it will take a while to explain this. For this instantiation, `new Cylinder(height, x, y, radius);`, you need a constructor like this `public Constructor(double height, double x, double y, double radius) {this.height = height; this.x = x; this.y = y; this.radius = radius}`

Comment: public Cylinder() {// constructor
        super();
        height = 0.0;
    }

    public Cylinder(double x, double y, double r, double h) {
        super(x, y, r);//call to the two-argument constructor
        height = h;
    }

Comment: Does your `Shape class` have a Shape(double, double, double) constructor?

Comment: public abstract class Shape implements Comparable{
   public double area() { return 0.0; }
   public double volume() { return 0.0; }
   public abstract String getName();  
   
   public int compareTo(Object o){
       //double a = area();
       //double b = ((Shape)o).area();
       
       if(this.area() < ((Shape)o).area()){
           return -1;
       }
       else if (this.area() > ((Shape)o).area()){
           return 1;
       }
         return 0;
   }
}

Comment: I don't see a `Shape` constructor anywhere in there.  You're trying to call `super(double double, double)`, but there is not `Shape(double, double, double)` constructor.

Comment: ok, i was following what the professor said, i have identical code to his, but the only thing that he told us is to implement Comparable. Also, the way that he wanted us to do it was for pointer to extend Shape and Square to extend pointer. So do i need to to add Shape(double, double, double) to Shape?

Comment: Comparable to Shape or the rest of subclasses?

Comment: I wish I could post the rest of my subclasses so you could see all my code and who is extending who

Comment: I figure that part out.  The only thing is that is not sorting the area or volume. Only prints unsorted.  Is this is because I have to implement comparable to each subclass?

Comment: Cannot find symbol: getArea () In class shape and Point is not an abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo (object)